# Create new Customer Page and Link in Customer Dashboard

Tags: customer, customer-account

I have been working on [this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page) and [this](http://istockphp.com/magento/adding-custom-page-to-the-customer-account-dashboard/) tutorial to add my custom link in customer account dashboard and then clicked on that link, open my custom page.

I have changed the Namespace and Module name. So far I am successful in adding a new link in dashboard, but when click on that link, it shows me blank page (**no 404 error**). I see below image and no block loading my `.phtml` file when the URL is `http://localhost/magento_18/index.php/customer/modulename/`

[image]

Below is my code for the module.

**config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_Modulename>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Namespace_Modulename>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <helpers>
                <modulename>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Helper</class>
                </modulename>
            </helpers>
            <resources>
                <modulename_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                        <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_setup>
                <modulename_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_write>
                <modulename_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_read>
            </resources>
            <blocks>
                <namespace_modulename>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Block</class>
                </namespace_modulename>
            </blocks>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <namespace_modulename>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                        <frontName>modulename</frontName>
                    </args>
                </namespace_modulename>
                <customer>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                        <namespace before="Mage_Customer">Namespace_Modulename</namespace>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </customer>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <namespace_modulename module="Namespace_Modulename">
                        <file>modulename.xml</file>
                    </namespace_modulename>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <namespace_modulename module="Namespace_Modulename">
                        <file>modulename.xml</file>
                    </namespace_modulename>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

My **layout** at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/modulename.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="modulename">
                <name>Test Module</name>
                <path>customer/modulename/</path>
                <label>My Test Module</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <modulename_modulename_index translate="label">
        <label>My Test Module</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>My Test Module</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="core/template" name="modulename" template="modulename/customer/modulename.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </modulename_modulename_index>
</layout>
```

My **controller** at `app\code\community\Namespace\Modulename\controllers\ModulenameController.php`

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_ModulenameController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    protected function _getSession() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }

    public function preDispatch() {

        parent::preDispatch();
        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $loginUrl = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this, $loginUrl)) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }

    public function indexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

Someone pls help and guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change path to "modulename" instead of "customer/modulename" in your layout customer.xml. Your router's frontname is "modulename" and not "customer/modulename".